# How to do "HTML FORM action=location.replace('nextpage.html')"?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The title is actually a failed attempt to achieve my goal. Specifically, I want to
1. Go to a page from main.html (say, to page1.html).
2. Collect data in a form on page1.
3. On Submit, go to page2.html (which saves data to database using PHP and announces result).
4. Click on "Ok" and go back to main menu page.
Seems reasonable, right?

Step 4 above is my problem.

Things I've tried:
1. Invoke history.back on Ok click in page2.
*This goes to page1 not main*
2. Invoke javascript location.href=main.html on "Ok" in page2
*This works and goes to main but clicking on Back button in main brings user back to page1. (not good)*
3. Many variations of using javascript history.replace() in action= and onSubmit() of page1.
*This works works and but inputs from form are **not** passed in query string to page2*)
4. Clear history.
*This appears to be impossible because of security concerns.*
5. Programmatically composing the query string for history.replace (from form inputs) on page1.
*This works but is very laborious, error-prone and horribly inelegant*

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

========= MY SOLUTION 4/8/16 ==============
I'm posting my final solution below for anybody that's interested.
In page1.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addarg(q,addend)
{
  qnew = q + addend;
  return( qnew );
}

function Next()
{
  // GET INPUT VALUES FROM FORM
  frm = document.forms["MainForm"];
  first   = frm.first.value;
  last    = frm.last.value;
  phone   = frm.phone.value;

  // COMPOSE QUERY
  query = "processForm.php";
  query = addarg( query, '?first='+first );
  query = addarg( query, '&last='+last   );
  query = addarg( query, '&phone='+phone );

  location.replace( query ); // chain to processing page
}
</script>

<form action="javascript:Next()" name="MainForm" method=GET>
  ...
</form>
```

When history.back() is issued from processForm.php, it returns to Main Menu as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the easier way to achieve this is to place a simple `<a href=main.html>Ok</a>` on your **page2.html**.

Then associate a flag (maybe a cookie) on this **main.html** which "instructs" **page1.html** to clear its form elements if it is not called by **main.html**, but from a "back" button (by refreshing meta, for example, or by loading **page1.html#randomnum**, where randomnum is a value you find real time to force your browser understand this is not the "old" **page1.html** but a "new" **page1.html**, helping browser not to get this from cache but from web).

The principle is: if **page1.html** is called by "back", it have to be a "clear" **page1.html**, not showing any data input user eventually entered.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I will try it.

Comment: I tried the "randomnum" solution, but (I believe) this only prevents a *server-cached* page from being displayed: It does not prevent a browser history page from being displayed. I did not implement the clear-form on redisplay approach because it still would display the (empty) input form on "Back" - not the desired result.

Comment: I did have success with approach #5 above, but I'm not happy with the ugly/nasty coding involved.

Comment: You're right. The better scenario, yet following my approach (which I am not sure will solve all your problems, maybe some of them), would be to implement some kind of "intelligence" on **page1.html** for a good detection about from where the user is coming. That I was trying to say about cookies on **main.html**. The navigation path would be: 1) you're on main; 2) you request page1; 3) main saves a flag into a cookie; 4) page1 is about to be shown; 5) page1 reads the cookie; 6) page1 show proper content; 7) if no cookie is present, page1 force the clearing of form elements.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. But I think the suggested logic is also too complicated (I have a lot of pages to modify). I think the cookie idea would work: maybe even inserting some logic into page1 to detect that we are coming back, and inserting some logic in the <HEAD> of page1 via php to redirect to main. Still sounds too hairy for my taste. But nonetheless, I'm marking the question as answered to acknowledge your help.

Comment: I really thank you. And again you're right: making a website "responsive", as it is fashion to say nowadays, or with some "inteligence", "active", "dynamic" whatever, costs hard coding. This can be confirmed by the variety of fanny naming javascript libraries that make coders crazy. Best luck for you. Thanks.