# JMS Topic context lookup issue

Tags: java, jms, mq, jms-topic

I am trying to lookup a JMS TopicConnectionFactory using JNDI in Websphere Application Server. I have done the jndi setup correctly in the server. I have deployed my application in the server.

I have designed 3 java classes for Sender/Reciever/Listener. Then after deploying the WAR in the server, I have first tried to run the Receiver Code as a standalone java application. However it failed with error as :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManag‌​er.java:242)

Attaching my code snippet below :

```
/**
 * SENDER CLASS
 */
package com.jms.topic;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicPublisher;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;



/**
 * @author db2admin
 *
 */
public class JMSTopicSender {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws JMSException 
     * @throws NamingException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext();  
        TopicConnectionFactory f=(TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("myTopicConnectionFactory");  
        TopicConnection con=f.createTopicConnection();  
        con.start(); 

        TopicSession ses=con.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic t=(Topic)ctx.lookup("myTopic");
        TopicPublisher publisher=ses.createPublisher(t);
        TextMessage msg=ses.createTextMessage();  
        msg.setText("Hello World");

        publisher.publish(msg);
        System.out.println("Message successfully sent.");



    }

}





/**
 *  RECEIVER CLASS
 */
package com.jms.topic;

import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSubscriber;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;



/**
 * @author db2admin
 *
 */
public class JMSTopicReciever {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {  
            //1) Create and start connection  
            InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext();  
            TopicConnectionFactory f=(TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("TCF");  
            TopicConnection con=f.createTopicConnection();  
            con.start();  
            //2) create topic session  
            TopicSession ses=con.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  
            //3) get the Topic object  
            Topic t=(Topic)ctx.lookup("jndi/myTopic");  
            //4)create TopicSubscriber  
            TopicSubscriber receiver=ses.createSubscriber(t);  

            //5) create listener object  
            JMSTopicListener listener=new JMSTopicListener();  

            //6) register the listener object with subscriber  
            receiver.setMessageListener(listener);  

            System.out.println("Subscriber1 is ready, waiting for messages...");  
            System.out.println("press Ctrl+c to shutdown...");  
            while(true){                  
                Thread.sleep(1000);  
            }  
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}











/**
 * LISTENER CLASS
 */
package com.jms.topic;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

/**
 * @author db2admin
 *
 */
public class JMSTopicListener implements MessageListener {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{  
            TextMessage msg=(TextMessage) m;  
            System.out.println("following message is received:"+msg.getText());  
        }catch(JMSException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Here is my JNDI Connection details :

[image: My JNDI lookup in Websphere App Server]

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: I am getting the below error :

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:242)

Comment: @JoshMc :  I have already added the error.. still pasting it once again.. please see below :


    **Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManag‌​er.java:242**

Comment: @JoshMc : Yes .. I have deployed the application WAR file in WAS. Then while tryinh to run the receiver java file as standalone java application I am getting the error.

Comment: No it doesn't indicate that. Its deployed in WAS but also I am trying to run as a standalone java application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In J2SE, you need to specify the class of the initial context factory use by WAS like this :

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://<your WAS server>:<port usually 2809>");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);
```

[Details here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cjq0000_.html)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with INITIAL_CONTEXT_LOOKUP.

Comment: What I mean is that people usually just click "edit" under the question and append to the end a solution. 
 Here are a few exampes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825426/how-to-tokenize-scan-or-split-this-string-of-email-addresses
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909386/make-panels-invisible-amchart
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759037/django-weighted-query-annotated-values
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429982/how-to-do-html-form-action-location-replacenextpage-html