# Make Panels invisible amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I would like to make panels visible/invisible by button.

in this [sample](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/adding-removing-panel/) remove/add panels.
But when adding, I need to make a panel and settings again.

I would like to just make panels visible/invisible not delete.

I have googled around and not found samples.

Is it possible??

---

Thanks to `@Robbert` reply

I could hide the panel . like this .

```
    $(".amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1").hide();
```

However it does not re-adjust the each panel size.

If I call the

So I try like this .

```
$(".amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1").hide();
chart.panels[1].percentHeight = 1;
chart.validateNow();
```

it hide the panel and adjust the each panel height.

However, if you use `validateNow()` when `percentHeight = 1;`

this error happens.

```
  amcharts.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined
    at b.fixVLine (amcharts.js:26)
    at b.adjustBalloonCoordinate (serial.js:17)
    at b.showBalloon (amcharts.js:5)
    at b.handleCursorMove (serial.js:8)
    at b.dispatchMovedEvent (amcharts.js:27)
    at b.syncWithCursorReal (amcharts.js:28)
    at b.syncWithCursor (amcharts.js:28)
    at b.handleCursorChange (amstock.js:2)
    at b.a.inherits.b.fire (amcharts.js:1)
    at b.dispatchMovedEvent (amcharts.js:27)
```

---

my final solution is like this , not use css, but prepare variable `panelBack` for panel backup.

```
//removing ...
pos = //panel position.
var panelBack = chart.panels[pos];
chart.removePanel(chart.panels[pos]);
chart.validateNow();

//adding...
chart.addPanelAt(panelBack,1);
chart.validateNow();
```

Comment: Even if you can hide a panel using CSS or whatever other outside method, I advice to stick with amCharts API methods (removing a panel and calling `validateNow`). If you don't, you might get unexpected error messages like the one you mentioned as amCharts thinks the panel is still there (which technically it is).

Comment: Thanks Robbert, Finally I use amchart API to remove. updated my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source of the demo, you'll see that the second Stock Panel gets a classname of `amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1`. You could hide it using CSS:

```
.amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1 {
  display: none;
}

.amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1 * {
  /* hide SVG nodes as well */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

However, amCharts itself is not aware that this panel is hidden, so it will not re-adjust the height of the first stock panel when "removing" it.

I would advice following the method as seen in the example.

Comment: Oh really? can't find the  amcharts-stock-panel-div-stockPanel1 class... Is this generated by javascript??

Comment: Yes. amCharts assigns classnames to most elements (HTML and SVG nodes). You'll find them by using your browser's Developer Inspector tools

Comment: Thank you very much I found  the class name in console and succeeded in hide the panel.

Comment: As you mentioned ,it does not re-adjust the height so I need to more work-aroundway though.